# Mobius transformation and the Riemann sphere

Tags: complex-geometry, mobius-transformation, riemann-sphere

I [see](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation) that Möbius transformation is defined as
$$f(z) = \dfrac{az + b}{cz + d}, \qquad ad -bc \neq 0$$ on the extended complex plane $\mathbb{C} \cup \{ \infty\}$.

But further in the text

> Thus a Möbius transformation is always a bijective holomorphic
>   function from **the Riemann sphere to the Riemann sphere**

I understand, that there are inverse stereographic projections which maps points in $\mathbb{C}$ to the Riemann sphere.

So, what is going on formally? Do we just name(associate) points on the "standard" unit sphere (like around the $(0,0,0)$ with unit radius) with the name $z$ of the pre-image under some "standard" inverse stereographic projection?

[image: visualization of the inverse projection]
I.e., let

- $S^2$ be a Riemann Sphere,
- $\psi : \mathbb{C} \cup \{\infty\} \to S^2$ be an inverse stereographic projection to it,
- $z_s = \psi(z)$

Then, do we technically define $f_S : S^2 \to S^2$ as
$$f_S = \psi \circ f \circ \psi^{-1}?$$

$^{1}$ please ignore the shading cone lines in the image

Comment: You are right, in some sense we "identify" the sphere $S^2$ with the projective line $\mathbb{P}^1:=\mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty\}$ via the stereographic projection.